# Zend2 Framework - Doctrine ORM giving Mapping Exception

Tags: zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use Doctrine 2 ORM for one of my Zend2 applications. I did the setup within the application using Doctrine modules with the help of composer.

I'm able to persist the data to the database, but when i make a find() call on the object manager it is giving me a Mapping Exception, with the following message.

```
Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException
File:
/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:96
Message:
Class 'User' does not exist
```

Below are the Doctrine settings added under the Application module config file

```
'driver' => array(
                'application_entities' => array(
                        'class' =>'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                        'cache' => 'array',
                        'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Entity')
                ),

                'orm_default' => array(
                        'drivers' => array(
                                'Application\Entity' => 'application_entities'
                        )
                )
        )
),
```

This is the User Entity created under Application\src\Entity folder

```
<?php
namespace Application\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 *  @ORM\Entity
 */
class User {
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @var int
 */
protected $user_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @var int
 */
protected $network_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 * @var string
 */
protected $network_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 * @var string
 */
protected $job_title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 * @var string
 */
protected $location;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 * @var string
 */
protected $first_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 * @var string
 */
protected $last_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @var string
 */
protected $url;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @var string
 */
protected $img_url;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @var string
 */
protected $department;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @var string
 */
protected $email_address;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 * @var string
 */
protected $verified;

/**
 * @return the int
 */
public function getUserId() {
    return $this->user_id;
}

/**
 * @param int $user_id
 */
public function setUserId($user_id) {
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return the int
 */
public function getNetworkId() {
    return $this->network_id;
}

/**
 * @param int $network_id
 */
public function setNetworkId($network_id) {
    $this->network_id = $network_id;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return the string
 */
public function getNetworkName() {
    return $this->network_name;
}

/**
 * @param string $network_name
 */
public function setNetworkName($network_name) {
    $this->network_name = $network_name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return the string
 */
public function getJobTitle() {
    return $this->job_title;
}

/**
 * @param string $job_title
 */
public function setJobTitle($job_title) {
    $this->job_title = $job_title;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return the string
 */
public function getLocation() {
    return $this->location;
}

/**
 * @param string $location
 */
public function setLocation($location) {
    $this->location = $location;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return the string
 */
public function getFirstName() {
    return $this->first_name;
}

/**
 * @param string $first_name
 */
public function setFirstName($first_name) {
    $this->first_name = $first_name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return the string
 */
public function getLastName() {
    return $this->last_name;
}

/**
 * @param string $last_name
 */
public function setLastName($last_name) {
    $this->last_name = $last_name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return the string
 */
public function getUrl() {
    return $this->url;
}

/**
 * @param string $url
 */
public function setUrl($url) {
    $this->url = $url;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return the string
 */
public function getImgUrl() {
    return $this->img_url;
}

/**
 * @param string $img_url
 */
public function setImgUrl($img_url) {
    $this->img_url = $img_url;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return the string
 */
public function getDepartment() {
    return $this->department;
}

/**
 * @param string $department
 */
public function setDepartment($department) {
    $this->department = $department;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return the string
 */
public function getEmailAddress() {
    return $this->email_address;
}

/**
 * @param string $email_address
 */
public function setEmailAddress($email_address) {
    $this->email_address = $email_address;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return the boolean
 */
public function getVerified() {
    return $this->verified;
}

/**
 * @param boolean $verified
 */
public function setVerified($verfied) {
    $this->verified = $verfied;
    return $this;
}
```

}

Now, when I do persist operation on the above entity from Application module's IndexController, it is working fine. But when I do the find operation using the same object mapper in the same IndexController, it is giving the mapping exception.

Below is how I'm doing this:

```
$objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
$objectManager->persist($user);
$objectManager->flush();
$user = $objectManager->find('User', $uniqueID);
```

Can anyone help me with this issue??

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity is not called `User` but `Application\Entity\User`. So replace this line:

```
$user = $objectManager->find('User', $uniqueID);
```

With this:

```
$user = $objectManager->find('Application\Entity\User', $uniqueID);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked!!!! DO you know any kind of document that clearly explains Doctrine 2 ORM???

Comment: I can't say nothing more than the Doctrine manual itself http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/index.html There is not much documentation about namespaced entities, as all senior developers know to use the full qualified class name (FQCN in short)